# Generating random numbers of exponential distribution

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double ran_expo(lambda){
    double u;

    u = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);

    return -log(1- u) / lambda;
}
```

I am using this (I do not put other parts of the codes here) to generate random numbers of an exponential distribution `lambda = 0.05`. (Probability density function being `lambda * exp(-lambda * x)`).

However, I always get very small numbers, such as  `0.000041`, or something like `1.#INF00` (what is this?).

In fact, for exponential distribution with `lambda = 0.05`, numbers generated should be quite large, namely most are not far from 30. My results are very weird. In addition, the degree of precision is not satisfactory, only to 10^(-6). I tried `long double`, but it is still like this.

I am using DEV C++ under windows.

Comment: What is the type of `lambda`?

Comment: lambda isn't a double in your code

Comment: You mean I should write something like (double)lambda?

Comment: The mean of your distribution is 30, but that doesn't mean most of the values you generate should be near that. The mode is actually 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you did not declare the type for `lambda`, having corrected that the results are in the range you seek. If undeclared, old compilers will assume it to be `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

double ran_expo(double lambda){
    double u;
    u = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
    return -log(1- u) / lambda;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (i=0; i<20; i++)
        printf("%f\n", ran_expo(0.05));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
0.025040
16.582459
4.296027
33.079902
17.589123
13.073084
8.624299
45.254803
34.611211
27.454302
3.825699
39.168172
24.790600
14.411160
7.247698
0.301951
1.917010
9.065004
3.187146
3.627885
```

Comment: Thanks, I was doubtful at first about your range of random numbers (concerned about `log(0)`) but I see you subtracted from `1`.

Comment: There is a glaring fault in my answer. There is a difference between assuming that `int` is the default type, and declaring `int lambda`, but I don't know what it is. In the first case, every result is `-0.000000`. But with the explicit `int` type every result is `1.#INF00`, as you would expect, the result of div 0. (MSVC).

Answer (score 0):

I threw your code *verbatim* into [code chef](https://www.codechef.com/ide), it looks like it works fine. Compiler is gcc c++ 4.9.2 . This code prints out `36.6751`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double ran_expo(double lambda){
    double u;

    u = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);

    return -log(1- u) / lambda;
}


int main() {
    cout << ran_expo(0.05);
    return 0;
}
```

Works the same way in C, too (again, gcc 4.9.2):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double ran_expo(double lambda){
    double u;

    u = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);

    return -log(1- u) / lambda;
}


int main() {
    printf("%f\n", ran_expo(0.05));
    return 0;
}
```

Must be your compiler/libraries?