# probabilistic random number in c program for lock free skip list implementation

Tags: c

I want to generate a random number in which every higher number has half the probability of its predecessor that is if 1 appears 4 times 2 should appear 2 times and three should appear one time and so on 
the programming language must be c

```
int getValue(int min,int max) {
    int i=0;
    while(i==0)
        i=rand()%max;
    int j=0;
    while(j==0) {
        printf("%d",j);
        j=rand()%i;
    }
    return j;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random numbers of exponential distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558230/generating-random-numbers-of-exponential-distribution)

Comment: int getValue(int min,int max) {
int i=0;
while(i==0)
i=rand()%max;
int j=0;
while(j==0)
{
printf("%d",j);
j=rand()%i;
 }
return j ;
}

Comment: What is a "probabilistic random number"??

Answer (score 1):

Following function may be used:

```
int prioritizdRand(int min, int max)
{

    int result=min;
    int randNum=rand();
    long int start=RAND_MAX/2;

    while(randNum > start)
    {
        if(result> max )
        {
           return min;
        }
        result++;
        start= (start + RAND_MAX)/2;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Looks wrong to me... lets assume `prioritizdRand(1, 2)`, then its very likely to hit the `result < max` condition before the `randNum > start` condition. But only the second condition would support the desired value distribution.

Comment: Might be true, but sacrificing correctness in order to ensure termination is a pretty tough deal. A little fine tuning on the involved numbers would probably reach the termination goal. Part of the problem is, that you assign a portion of `1/pow(2, max-min)` from your random number space to results that are not valid.

Comment: The exponent for this portion might be off by one, but as already commented, if you just analyze the `prioritizdRand(1, 2)` it's very clear: `1/2` for `result=1`, `1/4` for `result=2`, `1/4` remaining, which will also lead to `result=2` because of the `result < max` condition. Correct distribution would be `2/3` for `result=1` and `1/3` for `result=2`

Comment: Good change. Still not exact (`3/4` `result=1`, `1/4` `result=2`) but the error is far smaller and it will hardly affect the result for larger numbers. Since a technical application (skip list) was mentioned in the question, this should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by normalizing the requested range (later just add `min` to the random generated number):

```
int max_rnd = max - min;
```

Then generate a equally distributed random number in the range `1` to `pow(2, max_rnd+1) - 1`

```
int rnd_limit = (1 << (max_rnd + 1)) - 1;
int rnd = (rand() % rnd_limit) + 1;
```

Round down the base-2-logarithm of the generated random number. The translation of `rnd` will follow this pattern:

```
floor(log2(1)) -> 0
floor(log2(2)) -> 1
floor(log2(3)) -> 1
floor(log2(4)) -> 2
...
floor(log2(7)) -> 2
floor(log2(8)) -> 3
...
floor(log2(15)) -> 3
...
```

So the distribution of results will be the reverse of the expected (double instead of half for higher numbers) but thats easy to change. Effectively, the `floor(log2(rnd))` is computing the position of the highest 1 bit in `rnd`, so it can be implemented with a bitshift loop:

```
int log2_rnd = 0;
while ((rnd >> log2_rnd) != 1)
{
    ++log2_rnd;
}
```

Time for the actual result:

```
return (max_rnd - log2_rnd) + min;
```

Not covered here: Accuracy of "equally distributed" numbers generated by `rand()` (specially in combination with modulo) and upper limit of generated numbers.

Answer (score 1):

a simplistic idea: start with value one, take a random number, add one to
value if random number is odd, bitshift one right, repeat

```
unsigned randhalf()
{
    unsigned ret = 1;
    int rnd = rand();
    while (rnd&1)
    {
        ++ret;
        rnd >>= 1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Or if upper and lower bounds are required:

```
int randhalf(int min, int max) // bounds are inclusive
{
    int ret = min;
    int rnd = rand();
    while (rnd&1 && ret<max)
    {
        ++ret;
        rnd >>= 1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This will only provide values that are larger than `min` by however many bits
`rand()` uses.

Comment: Very elegant (+1) but what about `min, max` values?